# How did the fingerprint of Jason Bourne fall into Russian hands?

Tags: the-bourne-supremacy, jason-bourne

How did the fingerprint of Jason Bourne fall into Russian hands, to the point that it was the thread to tug on to unravel treadstone? Why was this security breach not investigated?

1. They had to know he was a high value target
2. They had to know his location though he was in hiding
3. They had to infiltrate the CIA

Who is the mole, and what was leaked?

Comment: Can't answer definitely - but possibly Conklin and/or Abbott

Answer (score 5):

Well acording to [Born.Fandom.Com/Wiki](https://bourne.fandom.com/wiki/Kirill)

> Kirill originally frames Jason Bourne by planting his fingerprints and proceeds to kill the agent and the source, stealing the files and money and giving them to Russian oil magnate Yuri Gretkov.

Hope this is what you're searching for.

Comment: Good answer Bogdan and welcome to the site!

Answer (score 1):

While Bogden's answer is fine, I just want to clarify that Abbot was the clear source of the fingerprint, given his access to Bourne's files with the logical conclusion that the conspiracy to frame him was only concocted following the murder of Conklin and Bourne going to ground. Indeed, [**Born.Fandom.Com/Wiki**](https://bourne.fandom.com/wiki/Ward_Abbott), specifically states that "Unbeknownst to Landy and everyone else, Abbott is actually responsible and in league with Kirill and Gretkov."